# Impractical, Improbable, and Incredible

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, knowledge

> My functions are complex, I will fight your wars.
> A design that'll perplex, not bought at your stores.
>
> Carefully crafted to be awesome, as I'm stuffed with weapons of war,
> Hear the bullets around you blossom, as the people who use us want more.
>
> I fly through the air in a swirl of fire,
> No tricks are used here, no imaginary wire.
>
> Effort has been taken to make me a reality.
> So wait for the great day when you can have one of me.

What am I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i think the answer is a

> War robot or a Mech

Because

> It is filled with weapons and we all would like to have one

My functions are complex, I will fight your wars

> A war robot is complex and it will fight wars

A design that'll perplex, not bought at your stores.

> Its design will be jaw-droppingly awesome

Carefully crafted to be awesome, as I'm stuffed with weapons of war

> It is filled with all kinbds of missilkes and bullets

Hear the bullets around you blossom, as the people who use us want more.

> Nations will want more of war robots

I fly through the air in a swirl of fire

> The war robots, equipped with a rocket will fly around

No tricks are used here, no imaginary wire.

> I don't know how the war robots are related to this line

Effort has been taken to make me a reality

> It takes a lot of effort to make a war robot

So wait for the great day when you can have one of me.

> I would like to have one of them

-

> So the thing is that I came across this new game called 'War Robots' and drew an inspiration from that.

Comment: I'll accept this as correct. Do you mind expounding your answer though?

Comment: I will elaborate

Comment: Done! I elaborated this is final

Comment: @Joe-You-Know - "Imaginary wire" is a reference to "fly-by-wire" autopilots or something?

Comment: @malandy, something to that affect.

Answer (score 3):

Are you a

> DRONE?

My functions are complex, I will fight your wars.

> There are many uses for drones, including military functions.

A design that'll perplex, not bought at your stores.

> They’ve got really weird designs and they’re not available in stores.

Carefully crafted to be awesome, as I'm stuffed with weapons of war,

> Military drones have tons of weaponry at their disposal

Hear the bullets around you blossom, as the people who use us want more.

> The military want to use drones a lot because it saves manpower.

I fly through the air in a swirl of fire,

> They can fly.

No tricks are used here, no imaginary wire.

> Like legitimately fly.

Effort has been taken to make me a reality.

> They were always a fantasy design, but have been created in reality now.

So wait for the great day when you can have one of me.

> They’re becoming more popular and available to the general public.

Secret hint:

> The acrostic is MACHINE, which a drone definitely is.

Title:

> All descriptors of drones at the moment; impractical meaning drone delivery; improbable meaning unlikely that a working drone was created; incredible meaning heck yeah they are.

Comment: As I mentioned to QuantumTwinkie, this isn't the answer I'm looking for. Though some of the answers, can be what you described.

Comment: Yeah, I didn’t look at any of the comments on my phone before posting. Thanks @Joe-You-Know

Answer (score 2):

Are you a

> Flying car

My functions are complex, I will fight your wars.

> It has great technology in it.

A design that'll perplex, not bought at your stores.

> It is almost unheard of(to the past).

Carefully crafted to be awesome, as I'm stuffed with weapons of war,

> Wheels... yeah I have nothing

Hear the bullets around you blossom, as the people who use us want more.

> People will want one?

I fly through the air in a swirl of fire,

> They will fly.

No tricks are used here, no imaginary wire.

> Like really fly,

Effort has been taken to make me a reality.

> Engineers are working hard on it.

So wait for the great day when you can have one of me.

> I'll buy one!

Comment: Not the answer I was expecting. I can't wait to see the explanation for this one. You are along the right tracks though.

Comment: Nice edit. You're right in thinking of technology.

Comment: Oh, is it a rot13(Qebar)? @Joe-You-Know

Comment: It's not that, though these can be a type of rot13(Qebar)

Answer (score 2):

Just Guessing

> Missile? Maybe a nuclear missile

My functions are complex, I will fight your wars.

> Missile fights wars.

A design that'll perplex, not bought at your stores.

> Missiles are of course not bought at stores.

Carefully crafted to be awesome, as I'm stuffed with weapons of war,

> A missile is awesome but I am not sure abut the second part.

Hear the bullets around you blossom, as the people who use us want more.

> Many nations are striving towards a nuclear program

I fly through the air in a swirl of fire,

> Missiles fly with a trail of fire maybe...

No tricks are used here, no imaginary wire.

> No tricks , Straightforward uranium 235

Effort has been taken to make me a reality.

> A lot of efforts in making a missile

So wait for the great day when you can have one of me.

> every nation wants to have one

Comment: and what about rot13(jne ebobg ) or rot 13(jne quebar)?

Comment: This isn't the answer, but rot13(jne ebobg ) essentially is the answer I'm looking for. Though, I would call that a rot13(tvnag svtugvat ebobg, n zrpun, n thaqnz, be nal bgure fvzvyne anzr)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like...

> **Artificial Intelligence**

is it?

Comment: It is not, I don't think of this as flying, typically.

Answer (score 1):

A

> [Mech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mecha)?
>
>  Because it is filled with weapons, usually can fly, impractical to build, improbable to be funded, and incredible, as it is a big phenomena...

Also because it's more specific than Siddhant Chutke's

> "War Robot"

Comment: This is more what I had in mind, but I think this is what Siddhant meant, right?

Comment: @Joe-You-Know - Possibly, but "War Robot" is vague, it likely wouldn't have a pilot, it can be any shape, it's basically a war-only drone... Usually, robots aren't piloted, they're given orders and they just go. ... You might need to add more to your riddle to be more specific... ... That might not be allowed now, dunno.